# Ways to unlock a SQLite database when another program is accessing it?

Tags: c, sqlite, locked

I'm using sqlite3 in Linux and I currently have a problem. I have a database and 2 tables in it: db1 and db2. db1 has 3 columns: empID, empName, empAddr. db2 has just 1 column: empID and its value is set to 0 by default.

I created a C program that continuously polls the 2nd database db2 for any changes in the value of empID. Depending on the new value of empID in db2, the program fetches the corresponding info from db1. For example, if the value of empID in db2 is changed to 1, the program looks for the information (empName and empAddr) from db1 that corresponds to an empID equal to 1. However when I run 2 terminals: 1 for manually changing the value of empID in db2 and another 1 for running the C program, I encountered the problem of a locked database. While the program is running and accessing the database, I want to change the value of empID in db2 but I understand that since my C program is accessing it, I cannot update the value of empID (unless I close the terminal running the program). So my question is, is there a way to update/change the value of empID in db2 while I'm accessing db2 through my program? Answers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite has a single locking mechanism -- lock the entire .sq3 file!

You could set the pragma for read uncommitted in hte "select"ing program  [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_read_uncommitted)

However using a database to send a message is like using the barn to send a letter.

Comment: how do i insert into the program the pragma statement?

Comment: You just "execute" the pragma same as any other SQL statement.

Comment: OK thank you, I have a new problem though. The PRAGMA statement just worked once. For example, while my program is polling the table, I changed the table's content and my polling program reacted accordingly. But when I tried to change the table's content again, the same error occurred: database is locked. Could this be fixed such that the table's content may be changed as many times as possible?

Comment: No, I was wrong. This is the sequence of events that happen: I change the table's content while the program is polling it. Change happened and the program reacted correctly. When I try to change the table's content again, the database is locked error occurs. When I issue the update command again, the change successfully takes place and the program reacts correctly. Why is this so? Why do I need to re-issue the command? Is the database locked for a couple of seconds?